# How to prevent Zero from appearing in Calculator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

I am writing a FreeCodeCamp Calculator. The problem that I am working on right now is repeating operators. For example, if I press "5" and then "+", but changed my mind and pressed "-", the history area should display "5-" instead of "5+". However, with my code, it display "5+0-". Therefore, I realize that I will need to fix the "Zero" problem as well.

The list I wanted to do for the "Zero" problem are:

1. If one press "0", allow it to appear in the history area. For example, if someone press "0" and then the operator, it should appear in the history area as "0-".
2. Otherwise, if someone press operator first without putting in any number, stop this method

Here is my code from this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/vWJxBW):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var mainMath = "0";
  var subMath = "0";
  var finalset = "";
  var subMatharray = [];
  var oppArray = [];
  var equalPressed = false;
  var prevKey = "";
  update();
  
  $("button").click(function(){
    calculate($(this).attr("value"));
  });
  
  function calculate(keyitem) {
    console.log("buttonpress: " + keyitem);
    switch(keyitem) {
      case "clear":
        clearScreen();
        break;
      case "%":
        percentageScreen();
        break;
      case "/":
      case "*":
      case "+":
      case "-":
        addOperator(keyitem);
        break;
      case "plusminus":
        plusminusScreen();
        break;
      case "0":
      case "1":
      case "2":
      case "3":
      case "4":
      case "5":
      case "6":
      case "7":
      case "8":
      case "9":
        addNumber(keyitem);
        break;
      case ".":
        addDecimal(keyitem);
        break;
      case "=":
        solveEqual(keyitem);
        break;
    }
    update();
    };
 
  function clearScreen() {
     mainMath = "0";
     subMath = "0";
     prevKey = "";
     subMatharray = [];
     oppArray = [];
    if(mainMath.length > 0){
      $(".entry").css("font-size", "4em");
    }
    console.log("clearMain: " + mainMath);
    console.log("clearSub: " + subMath);
  };
  
  function plusminusScreen() {
     mainMath = -1 * mainMath;
    finalset = mainMath;
    console.log("plusminusMain: " + mainMath);
    console.log("plusminusFinal: " + finalset);
  };
  
  function addNumber(keyitem) {
    if (mainMath == "0"){
      mainMath = keyitem/*mainMath.replace("0", keyitem);*/
      finalset = mainMath;
      return;
      console.log("addedMainZero: " + mainMath);
      console.log("addedFinalZero: " + finalset);
    }
    if (equalPressed == true){
      mainMath = keyitem;
      subMath = "0";
      subMatharray = [];
      equalPressed = false;
      console.log("addNumberEqualmain: " + mainMath);
    }
    mainMath+=keyitem;
    finalset = mainMath;
    
    console.log("addedMain: " + mainMath);
    console.log("addedFinalset: " + finalset);
    console.log("addedarray: " + subMatharray);
    
    if(mainMath.length > 8){
      $(".entry").css("font-size", "1.5em");
    }
    
  };
  
  function addOperator(keyitem){
    
    if (equalPressed == true){
      subMatharray = [];
      equalPressed = false;
      console.log("addOpEqualarray: " + subMatharray);
    }
    /*if (mainMath == "0" && finalset !== "0"){
      mainMath = "0";
      subMatharray.push(keyitem);
      return;
      console.log("addedMainZero: " + mainMath);
      console.log("addedFinalZero: " + finalset);
    }*/
    
    oppArray.push(keyitem);
    console.log("addOpArray: " + oppArray);
    var opkeyitem = "";
    
    subMatharray.push(mainMath);
    prevKey = "numbertest";
    
    if(prevKey == "numbertest") {
      subMatharray.push(keyitem);
      prevKey = "operatortest";
      console.log("addOpArraySubArrayElse: " + subMatharray);
      console.log("addOpArrayPrevKeyElse: " + prevKey);
    } /*else if (oppArray.length > 1 && prevKey == "operatortest") {
      subMatharray.pop();
      subMatharray.push("droubletest");
      oppArray = [];
      console.log("addOpArraySubArray: " + subMatharray);
      console.log("addOpArrayPrevKey: " + prevKey);
    } /*else if(prevKey == "numbertest") {
      subMatharray.push(keyitem);
      prevKey = "operatortest";
      console.log("addOpArraySubArrayElse: " + subMatharray);
      console.log("addOpArrayPrevKeyElse: " + prevKey);
    }*/
    
    subMath = subMatharray.join("");
    mainMath = "0";
    prevKey = keyitem;
    console.log("addOpSub: " + subMath);
    console.log("addOpMain: " + mainMath);
    console.log("addOpMainarray: " + subMatharray);
    console.log("equaltrueTest: " + equalPressed);
  };
  
  function addDecimal(keyitem){
    if (mainMath.indexOf(keyitem) === -1){
      if(mainMath == "0") {
        mainMath = "0" + keyitem;
        return;
      }
    } else {
        return;
      }
    addNumber(keyitem);
  };
  
  function solveEqual(keyitem) {
    subMatharray.push(finalset);
    subMath = subMatharray.join("");
    mainMath = eval(subMath);
    console.log("solveEqualresult: " + mainMath);
    console.log("solveEqualhistory: " + subMath);
    console.log("solveEqualarray: " + subMatharray);
    var finalresult = mainMath.toString();
    if(finalresult.length > 8){
      $(".entry").css("font-size", "1.5em");
    }
    equalPressed = true;
  };
  
  function update(){
  $("#answer").html(mainMath);
  $("#history").html(subMath);
};
  
});

/*Problems
2. I need to work on percentage button soon...
3. fix the problem if someone click an operator more than one.
*/
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400');
h1, h2, h3, p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
html, body{
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  padding: 160px 0;
}
.calculatorbox {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.calheader {
  text-align: center;
}
.calwindow {
  background: #000000;
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: column; /* Safari */
  flex-direction:         column;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.entry {
  font-size: 4em;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.entryhistory {
  font-size: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.entry p, .entryhistory p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}
sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}
 
sub {
  bottom: -0em;
}
.row {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.key {
  width: 75px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 22px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.key.btnspan {
  width: 150px;
}
.key.topcolor {
  background: #d9d9d9;
}
.key.orange {
  background: #ff8c00;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="calheader">
      <h2>Simple Calculator</h2>
    </div>
  <div class="calculatorbox">
    <div class="calwindow">
      <!-- ENTRY BOX -->
      <div class="entry">
        <p id="answer"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="entryhistory">
        <p id="history"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- BUTTONS -->
    <div class="calbuttons">
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key topcolor" value="clear">C</button>
        <button class="key topcolor" value="plusminus"><sup>+</sup>/<sub>−</sub></button>
        <button class="key topcolor" value="%">%</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="/">÷</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="7">7</button>
        <button class="key" value="8">8</button>
        <button class="key" value="9">9</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="*">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="4">4</button>
        <button class="key" value="5">5</button>
        <button class="key" value="6">6</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="-">−</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="1">1</button>
        <button class="key" value="2">2</button>
        <button class="key" value="3">3</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="+">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key btnspan" value="0">0</button>
        <button class="key" value=".">.</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="=">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All the action is happening in `function addOperator(keyitem)`. I have attempt to fix the "Zero" problem, but I commented it out so you can see fully what I am talking about. Here is the code that I commented out.

```
if (mainMath == "0" && finalset !== "0"){
      mainMath = "0";
      subMatharray.push(keyitem);
      return;
      console.log("addedMainZero: " + mainMath);
      console.log("addedFinalZero: " + finalset);
    }
```

I look forward to any suggestions or code solutions that can help me fix the "Zero" problem.

Comment: The problem, is in the addOperator function, you are pushing mainMath into the subMatharray, and you set mainMath to 0 towards the end of the addOperator function. 

So: we have addOperator first click -> adds mainMath, which happens to be right -> sets mainMath to 0 -> addOperator second click -> adds mainMath (which is 0) along with the operator -> sets mainMath to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I would reconsider the inital value from "0" to null to be able to split zero-logic and init-logic:

```
var mainMath = null;
// ...

function clearScreen() {
  mainMath = null;
  // ...
}

function addNumber(keyitem) {
  if (mainMath === null) { 
    mainMath = "0"; //hacky, I know, this requires more deep refactoring
  }
  // ...
}

function addOperator(keyitem){
  if(mainMath === null) {
    return; // this is the main point
  }
  // ...    
  mainMath = null;
  // ...
}

$("#answer").html(mainMath === null ? "0" : mainMath);
```

It's just an idea, and the approach should be improved, but the interim result you may try on your [codepen fork](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KyXpem).

Comment: @KristinaBressler If you want it to be shown, just show "0" when the value is null. I will update the answer and the fork

Comment: What about clear screen? I need to work on that properly so that I can test out the calculator repeatly

Comment: never mind, I think I fixed it by adding what you add to the function addNumber to Clear function `if (mainMath === null){
      mainMath = "0";
    }`

Comment: I'm almost there with my code. You can check out my current code at https://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/vWJxBW. With my adjustments and your help, I was able to stop the operators if they were entered first without any numbers.

Comment: `if (["/", "*", "+", "-"].indexOf(keyitem) > -1 && ["/", "*", "+", "-"].indexOf(prevKey) > -1) {
      oppArray.shift();
      opkeyitem = oppArray.toString();
      subMatharray.pop();
      subMatharray.push(opkeyitem);
      oppArray = [];
      prevKey = null;
    } else if(prevKey == null) {
      subMatharray.push(keyitem);
      prevKey = keyitem;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

In your "addOperator" function you'll just need a simple if statement, check whether or not the last character in your string is an operator. If it is then swap it, if it isn't than add the given operator

EDIT:

I looked through the code some more and looks like it's a little more complex than a single if statement and would require quite a bit of rewriting. All I can really offer is a different way of going about storing your values.

I would recommend storing an array of the actual button presses as soon as the button is pressed, and then modify that list within your individual button functions, *then* from that list generate you're display. For example, if the user were to press 1, +, 2, 3, -, +, = the array would look like this:

[] -> []

[1] -> [1]

[1,+] -> [1,+]

[1,+,2] -> [1,+,2]

[1,+,2,3] -> [1,+,23] // Checked by addNumber, concats numbers

[1,+,23,-] -> [1,+,23,-]

[1,+,23,-,+] -> [1,+,23,+]   // Checked by addOperator, swaps operator

[1,+,23,-,+,=] -> []   // Checked by solveEqual, solves then empties array

Having this as a global variable would allow your button functions to *modify* the array as opposed to *pushing* elements from the functions as it currently is, the benefit being you wouldn't be pushing elements that shouldn't be pushed like nulls or operators

Comment: Please read @Tyler Dahle's comment. This is the reason why I cannot simply do what you suggested....and the reason why I need to fix the "Zero" problem

Comment: You'll have to differentiate between when a key is actually pressed versus when you're grabbing from the display. From what I understand you're just taking from whatever is currently in the display as opposed to what the last key pressed was?

Comment: Following up the last comment, looks like your subMatharray will be able to do the trick as it lists all of the button presses. You'll just need to check the last index to see if it was an operator key, an actual zero/number, or if the operator is the first button pressed (then you would use the zero)

Comment: Could you write the solution?